# Is it possible to use Cinder with VS2013?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, cinder

Is it possible to use Cinder with VS2013?

From the official Cinder web site, the [download page](http://libcinder.org/download/) lists only VS2010 and VS2012 support:

[image]

Is there some other Cinder distribution that can be downloaded, and it's ready for use with VS2013?

---

**EDIT**

Someone in the comments suggested to try the VS2012 download with VS2013. I tried creating a simple project with TinderBox, and opened the solution in VS2013. After the usual VS2013's solution upgrade dialog-box, I tried to build, and I got the following errors:

> ```
> 1>------ Build started: Project: CinderTestVS2013, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
> 1>  CinderTestVS2013App.cpp
> 1>  Unknown compiler version - please run the configure tests and report the results
> 1>cinder_d.lib(gl.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1700' doesn't match value '1800' in CinderTestVS2013App.obj
> 1>cinder_d.lib(Renderer.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1700' doesn't match value '1800' in CinderTestVS2013App.obj
> 1>cinder_d.lib(Window.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1700' doesn't match value '1800' in CinderTestVS2013App.obj
> ...
>
> lots of similar errors ...
> ...
>
> 1>C:\Temp\CinderTests\CinderTestVS2013\vc11\Debug\CinderTestVS2013.exe : fatal error LNK1319: 55 mismatches detected
> ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
> ```

Comment: Have you tried the VS2012 download, and run into some problem?

Comment: I'm fairly sure I got Herb's name-drawing thing working with VS2013.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I got several errors (some of them added in the question).

Comment: Hmm, I think you will have to recompile Cinder itself using your compiler, so that the runtime version and everything matches between Cinder and your application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded the dev branch source code from here:

https://github.com/BanTheRewind/Cinder/tree/dev

and built it using VS2013 (there was actually a file missing from Boost, and I downloaded it from [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/boost/preprocessor/debug/error.hpp); after adding that file, compilation was successful).

Since there seemed to be no TinderBox working "out of the box" with VS2013, I used the "official" TinderBox (which can target VS2012), created a project using that TinderBox, and then opened this VS2012 project with VS2013.

After the conversion completed, I updated the references to include directories (*C/C++ | General | Additional Include Directories*) and library directories (*Linker | Additional Library Directories* and *Linker | Input | Additional Dependencies*) to point to the files of the aforementioned VS2013 dev branch.

The simple code I tested ran correctly.

However, is not as smooth as using the officially supported VS2012.
Looking forward to have an official VS2013 support (including TinderBox).

Answer (score 2):

There's a work in progress branch with VS2013 binaries on GitHub here: https://github.com/cinder/Cinder/tree/boost_155

See also these relevant forum posts on Cinder's forum, where I'd recommend asking this type of question for a faster response:

- https://forum.libcinder.org/topic/cinder-8-5-0-with-vs2013-and-boost-1-55-0
- https://forum.libcinder.org/topic/contribute-now-later-using-vs2013-and-boost-1-54-with-0-8-6-dev-branch

Comment: Thanks for the links. However, I prefer staying within the StackOverflow community/platform, if possible.